# How to fetch bit flags predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, ListOption) {
ListOption1 = 1 << 0,
ListOption2 = 1 << 1,
ListOption3 = 1 << 2
};

@interface SomeClass : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *listOption;
@end
```

I save the bit flags to coredata. How to make the fetch predicate like "SomeClass.listOption | ListOption1" Or "SomeClass.listOption & ListOption1"

Comment: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((listOption & %llu)>0)", ListOption1];`

Comment: Is that comment an answer to your own question?  If so, then you should add it as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((listOption & %llu)>0)", ListOption1];
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.